# Typescript update to 5+ breaks my project (WebStorm)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, express

I had to update typescript from 4.9.5 to 5+ (5.1.3), because one of the libraries I'm using released a fix that requires a new ts version.

After the update the typescript is yelling at console calls, react event dispatches etc. For example, this code in backend

```
console.log(chalk.green('test'))
```

Does not work anymore, with or without @types/chalk installed (no need to install types).

The error is:

**Argument types do not match parameters**

It cannot resolve the type import from prisma that worked before:

```
import {User} from '@prisma/client'
```

**Cannot resolve symbol 'User'**

TRPC router in backend are not working:
**Argument types do not match parameters**

The react code is not working as well. React-hook-form cannot register inputs, react refs are broken.

The new react-hook-form error is:

**Type argument cannot be inferred from usage**

---

**My backend tsconfig is:**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "module": "NodeNext",
      "esModuleInterop": true,
      "target": "ES2022",
      "moduleResolution": "NodeNext",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
      "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
      "isolatedModules": false,
      "strict": true,
      "noImplicitAny": true,
      "useUnknownInCatchVariables": true,
      "inlineSourceMap": true,
      "allowJs": true,
    },
    "ts-node": {
        "esm": true
    },
    "lib": ["esnext"]
}
```

**The client (react) one is:**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "lib": [
      "DOM",
      "DOM.Iterable",
      "ESNext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "types": [
      "vite/client"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ],
  "references": [{ "path": "./tsconfig.node.json"}]
}
```

It seems like there's a popular breaking change in ts 5, cause I can't find anything regarding these errors.

UPD: I face these issues on **Webstorm** 2022.2.2, VSCode have other errors. Restart doesn't help.

Comment: Does the error persist if you restart the typescript language server?

Comment: Yes. I restarted my pc and the problem is still here :(

Answer (score 1):

Had similar issue with typescript@5.1.3 on WebStorm@2022.2.3

What I did to solve this was:

1. Downgrade `typescript` to v4.9.5
2. Remove `.idea` directory
3. Restart WebStorm

Unfortunately it seems like there's some kind of bug with typescript@5 on WebStorm@2022.2. It's weird because the project using ts@5 worked fine on VSCode.